# Как удалить script src с помощью Pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, скрипт

Как удалить такой тег?
`<script src="/page/some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как удалить script src с помощью Pure JS?

При условии, что скрипты находятся в `head`.

```js
var head = document.querySelector('head'); // скрипты в head
var nodes = head.childNodes; // Дочерние элементы head
// Проходим по всем элементам
nodes.forEach(function(e, i) {
  // Remove tag or empty src
  if (e.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
    console.log(e.src); // e.src = '' // "удалит" скрипт
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    e.src = ''; // Удалит путь к файлу
    console.log(e.src); // Файл уже не подгружен
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Полное удаление элемента script
    // head.removeChild(e); // <--- Эта команда удалит весь элемент script
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
  }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только не вижу саму функция удаления. Только отображение в консоль.

Comment: @Lebedev `e.src=''` "уберает" путь файла.

Comment: А какая от этого есть польза? Разве скрипты не запущены к моменту появления в DOM?

Comment: @vp_arth из возможных вариантов - расширение для браузера, визуальное "удаления" (файл прячут).

Comment: Из вкладки Network не спрячешь) А чтобы это работало из расширения вероятно нужны немного другие методы. Если документ разобран и готов к querySelector - скрипт таки уже запущен...